# Strange Error message on google chrome

Tags: google-chrome

When some of the images load on my website I am getting the following warning:
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type image/x-png:

Does anyone know what this means?

Comment: Configure your server to deliver PNG images with `Content-Type: image/png`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my misunderstanding...You are displaying an image but the server does not understand the extension of the image and returns a default MIME type x-png. Some cases, the detected MIME type can differ from the generally accepted value for backward compatibility. And then it doesn't work.  A solution to solve this problem is to change the extension of your image.

Comment: _transferred with MIME type image/x-png_ – where does that say it was a _web page_?